# Calculating percent done for progress dialog

Tags: android, progress-bar

I am trying to use a progress dialog to show how long until 2 time intensive functions are done.

in my first function I have the total number to db entries and a counter for how many times i have gone through a do/while loop. when that gets done the progress dialog should be at 50%

so I do:

```
double total = (counter/dbEntries)*100; //counter and dbEntries are both int's
```

then I divide total by `2` because I want half the amount done because there are 2 functions

```
double realPercentDone = total/2.0;
```

so say `counter is 3` and `dbEntries is 36` that would equal `0.08 or 8% when multiplied by 100` but total is always 0. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `counter` and `dbEntries` are both integers then it is likely performing integer division in the parenthesis of your first expression. `3 div 36 = 0`.

Try changing it to something like this:

```
double total = 100.0 * counter / dbEntries;
```

or

```
double total = (1.0 * counter / dbEntries) * 100.0;
```

Note: use `100.0` and not `100` so as floating point calculations are done.

Answer (score 0):

You should either cast, or use the double type for `counter` and `entries`. I assume you're using ints currently, and as ints go, 3/36=0, and of course 0*100 is still 0.

Answer (score 0):

Also, note that if you always divide total by 2, then you will never get to 100%, you will range between 0% and 50%.

Comment: that is what i want to get because there are 2 different functions that get used 50% + 50% = 100%